# Ruby logic and linking job object to job application object for job board

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, associations

Working on creating a job board project where I have two models/objects: job and job_application. Have two enum roles setup as applicant and company. I set an invite action where a company can invite an applicant who's a user.

When an applicant is signed in they should be able to click the "Apply to Job" button and it redirects the applicant to the specific job_application form if the applicant was not invited. Also, if an applicant has not applied to a job, the "Withdraw from Job" button should not be an option.

I'm not exactly sure where I'm going wrong in the Ruby logic for the actions above

I want to list my current Ruby logic for app > views > job > show.html.erb:

```
<% if current_user.try(:role) == 'applicant' %>
        <div class="price-btn">
        <% if JobApplication.find_by(job_id: @job.id, user_id: current_user.id).nil? || JobApplication.find_by(job_id: @job.id, user_id: current_user.id).try(:status) == 'invited' %>
          <% if JobApplication.find_by(job_id: @job.id, user_id: current_user.id).nil? %>
            <%= link_to "Apply to Job", job_applications_path(user_id: current_user.id, status: 'applied', job_id: @job.id), method: :post, class: "btn btn-lg btn-dark"%>
          <% else %>
            <%= link_to "Apply to Job", new_job_job_applications_path(id: JobApplication.find_by(job_id: @job.id, user_id: current_user.id).try(:id), status: 'applied'), method: :post, class: "btn btn-lg btn-dark" %>
          <% end %>
        <% end %>
          <% if JobApplication.find_by(job_id: @job.id, user_id: current_user.id).nil? || JobApplication.find_by(job_id: @job.id, user_id: current_user.id).try(:status) == 'invited' %>
          <% if JobApplication.find_by(job_id: @job.id, user_id: current_user.id).nil? %>
            <%= link_to "Withdraw from Job", job_applications_path(user_id: current_user.id, status: 'rejected', job_id: @job.id), method: :post, class: "btn btn-lg btn-dark"%>
          <% else %>
              <%= link_to "Withdraw from Job", job_applications_path(id: JobApplication.find_by(job_id: @job.id, user_id: current_user.id).try(:id), status: 'rejected'), method: :post, class: "btn btn-lg btn-dark" %>
            <% end %>
          <% end %>
        </div>
      <% else %>
```

Comment: As a start it would helpful to introduce a variable or two so you are not re-running the same find query. `<% application = JobApplication.find_by(job_id: @job.id, user_id: current_user.id) %>`

Comment: I don't understand. What is the problem? Are you getting an error? Do you not see the button you expected? Does the button just look wrong?

Comment: @dbugger That will be my first step in making the code more readable.

Comment: @JaredBeck The 'apply to job' button is only allowing me to click on the button and automatically applies to the job without taking me to the job application. Not sure if there's a recommendation for the ruby logic?